# transactional Replication of millions of updates

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, transactional-replication

I have standard transactional replication setup from 2005 to 4 2008 subscribers. One of the tables that is replicated is updated several times from an agent job resulting in 6 million updates statements every morning which is causing massive deadlock chains on the subscribers.

I think the resolution is to change this to replicate just a stored procedure call?  Do I simply have to add the new stored procedure into the publication & add the article at the subscriber ?

I have attempted this as still seem to be transmitting all of the update statements, I have added the article properties to replicate the call of the stored procedure as well but still seeing all rows in replication monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Panic over !

When adding the stored procedure to the Article, in the properties there is a setting called 'replicate'. By default this is schema only. When i changed this to Execution of the stored procedure' instead of 'Execution in a serialized transaction of the SP'. and restarted all the agents, it worked as one transaction this time

Comment: You cannot amend these settings of articles either, you must do it at creation time, or drop and add at a later date, so be careful as this will invalidate your snapshot